# Does equipment meld and/or resize with your body when under elemental body?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment, polymorph

When close to humanoid in form your equipment does not meld with you while under polymorph effects. The spell [elemental body](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-body/) 1-4 changes you into an psudo-elemental but does not say if your form is humanoid.

Elementals are shown as having a head, torso, arms, and usually legs. Does this mean they are are close enough to the humanoid shape that your gear is not melded into you?

The [elemental type](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Elemental) and [elementals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/) do not say they are humanoid. The pages do mention that humanoid forms are possible.

> Proficient with natural weapons only, unless generally humanoid in form, in which case proficient with all simple weapons and any weapons mentioned in its entry.

If your gear is not melded into you, does it change size to fit your new size like enlarge/reduce person does?

Mostly I am asking if bow wielding druid is still able to use their bow when under the effects of all versions of the elemental body spell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, the equipment melds**

From the [Polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) subschool:

> When you cast a polymorph spell that changes you into a creature of the animal, dragon, **elemental**, magical beast, plant, or vermin type, all of your gear melds into your body.

That includes all weapons, so your druid would not be able to wield a bow.

Comment: Unless you grab the bow after polymorphing, or somehow create this bow using magic.

Comment: As a GM I would let the caster choose whether the stuff melds or not, but that's a houserule. Anyway, it costs nothing to ask your GM!

Comment: @AnneAunyme that can become a significant balance issue, armor/shield bonuses are an obvious example, and plenty of magic items would be useful while polymorphed but can't due to this rule (see wands & scrolls). There are specific ways around this rule, particularly the [Polymorphic Pouch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/polymorphic-pouch/).

Comment: @WeirdFrog: armor would not change size, so unless you stay at the same size there is no point keeping it. Shields would take you a hand, that you may want to need for your natural attacks. Wands and scrolls need you to speak and to have hands to wave them... I really don't see this as a real balance issue but I guess chat would be more appropriate if you want to talk about it.

Comment: @WeirdFrog that pouch is really neat, but doesnt help if part of what I want is for the bow to resize with me like equipment does with enlarge person.